# How can I use mfglabs commons-aws-sqs library for scala now that bintray was sunset

Tags: scala, bintray

On one of my company's services we are using an external library of **mfglabs**'s **commons-aws-sqs** library (
https://github.com/MfgLabs/commons-aws
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mfglabs/commons-aws-sqs_2.11/0.12.2
)

which was hosted on bintray, which was sunset few weeks ago on May 1'st.

How can I keep using this library now that bintray was sunset?

Comment: Bintray is still available in read only but I guess not for "private" repositories. Your best chance is to contact the maintainer so that they publish on Maven central or fork it and publish it in your company's repository.

Comment: However considering that it's not maintained, it might be an opportunity to not use it anymore and find other options..